# What is the Undiscovered challenge in Arid Badlands

Tags: borderlands-2

There's a hidden Badass challenge in Arid Badlands that shows up as Undiscovered until you find it. Unlike every other challenge I can't find the details on youtube, wikis, and even after digging through a long forum thread of people trying all the absurd crap they could think of, no one seems to know what it is.

What is the Undiscovered challenge in Arid Badlands and how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a phantom challenge:
According to these patch notes
(http://www.polygon.com/2012/11/14/3644610/borderlands-2-pc-patch-drops-today-squashes-bugs-and-corrects-broken), a bug was fixed that was "alerting players to an undiscovered challenge that is inaccessible".

Make sure you've downloaded the latest patch and check again - you should no longer see an undiscovered challenge.

Comment: Apologies for poor formatting. The mobile version of the site is not that helpful and I can't remember the proper link formatting! Will fix later if no kind soul does it first.

Comment: Well no wonder no one found it out. Good find.

Answer (score -1):

the only challenges i have for the badlands are the lost echos, open the chest at the bus stop and find the hidden claptrap, it's probably one of those

Comment: Unless you're on the latest version (PC at least) the undiscovered challenges don't show up until you discover/unlock them. Those used to be the only ones for me too, but the hidden one since appeared.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be to defeat Bonehead 2.0?

EDIT: I can verify that the X360 version only has those 3 Badass challenges (Bonehead/Echos/Claptrap).  I have all updates, have done all sidequests, and been to all locations in the Badlands, in addition to being Lvl50.  If there is an undiscovered challenge in the PC version, then it may be PC-specific, or maybe some issue with the PC version.

Comment: It's not; I've defeated him a few times.

Comment: Fair enough.  If I find anything, I'll let you know.